# Зачем нужна команда break, если цикл while и так завершится, когда значение х превысит num?

Tags: python

```
def count_primes(num):
    список_чисел = [2] #список чисел
    x = 3 #изменяемый список чисел до 100 (но начиная с 3 с шагом 2 до 100 мы не дойдем)
    if num <2:
        return 0
    while x <= num: #цикл выполняется, пока х не больше 100
        for y in range (3,x,2): #(берем число от 3 до х-1 с шагом 2, на которое будем делить)
            if x%y == 0:
                x += 2
                break
        else:
            список_чисел.append(x)
            x += 2
    print (список_чисел)
    return len(список_чисел)
```

Не понимаю почему, если убрать break итоговые значения отличаются на 2 числа. Если проверка идёт только до 100. Как туда попадает число 101? И какую роль во всём этом играет break?
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97] - с braek
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 95, 97, 101] - без break

Comment: Чтобы прервать цикл for при соблюдении условия `if x%y == 0:` попутно увеличив значение x на 2

Comment: Не надо плодить несколько вопросов с одним и тем же кодом. Закройте один из них, вы можете править с помощью ссылки `Править` под вопросом

Comment: Break нужен, чтобы досрочно выйти из цикла при соблюдении каких-то условий, не дожидаясь окончания цикла.